# Unhide a column in ALV via REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY

Tags: field, catalog, alv

I have two SAP systems with the same program.

The column **Nome 2** is displayed in the ALV grid of the system1 but in the ALV grid of the system2 is hidden and when select the details you could see the **Nome 2** value in both sistems.

The program uses field catalog to pass a list of fields to display in ALV, and also uses the function `REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY`.

[image]

[image]

I would be very pleased if someone have any suggestions that could solve it.

Regards,

Nataly

Comment: Visibility may be affected by logon attributes (language or mandant), you also can check if there is some variant affecting this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `no-out` property of fieldcatalog in system 1. It seems to be enabled there:

You suppose to search lines like this:

```
IF T_FIELDCAT-FIELDNAME = 'NOME1'.
    T_FIELDCAT-NO_OUT = 'X'.
    MODIFY T_FIELDCAT INDEX sy-tabix.
ENDLOOP.
```

Remove `NO-OUT` line and voilá!